# Host based routing on Load Balancer listeners

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

In Load Balancer listeners, can it make sense to push all the listener rules into one rule? In our settings currently, all are looking at the host header for a non-HTTPS connection and redirecting to the provided host with an HTTPS connection. Is there is a limit to the number of host rules or does separating them perform better? Can you please give suggestions?

example:

```
    1.arn...3e0bb           IF                                       THEN
                            host is abc.com OR xyz.com               Redirect to https://#{host}:443/#{path}?#{query}
                                                                     status code HTTP_301
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a rule limit **per load balancer** of 100, so splitting up the listeners won't really help much :). However your design pattern is perfectly normal. I also usually set up host-based routing on a single listener. Also performance-wise I never had any issues with many listener rules.

For all load balancer quotas, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-limits.html

Comment: Thanks, LRutten , so , I don't need to do any changes right !!